# Gnuplot bar chart with personalize interval on x-axis

Tags: plot, data-visualization, bar-chart, gnuplot, blast

I'm new using gnuplot and i would like to replicate this plot: https://images.app.goo.gl/DqygL2gfk3jZ7jsK6

I have a file.dat with continuous value between 0 and 100 and i would like to plot it, subdivided in intervals ( pident> 98, 90 < pident < 100...) Etc. And on y-axis the total occurrences.

I looked everywhere finding a way but still I cannot do it.

Thank you !
sample of the data, with the value and the counts:

```
33.18 5
43.296 1
33.19 1
27.168 5
71.429 11
30.698 9
47.934 1
43.299 3
30.699 3
37.092 2
24.492 2
24.493 2
24.494 7
47.938 1
24.497 1
37.097 8
37.099 2
33.824 7
51.111 15
59.025 2
62.553 2
62.554 2
57.867 2
33.826 2
62.555 1
33.827 5
62.556 2
33.828 1
59.028 1
46.429 11
51.117 1
75.158 2
27.621 1
27.623 1
27.624 2
37.5 113
37.6 2
32.313 8
27.626 3
37.7 3
32.314 1
67.797 3
27.628 2
32.316 2
37.9 1
61.044 1
43.81 5
32.317 8
32.318 2
43.82 4
32.319 2
43.83 2
37.551 3
61.048 1
48.993 6
29.43 2
```

This is the code tried so far (where i also calculate the mean):

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
set noytics

# Find the mean
mean= system("awk '{sum+=$1*$2; tot+=$2} END{print sum/tot}' hist.dat")

set arrow 1 from mean,0 to mean, graph 1 nohead ls 1 lc rgb "blue"
set label 1 sprintf(" Mean: %s", mean) at mean, screen 0.1

# Histogram
binwidth=10
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)
plot 'hist.dat' using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code you have tried so far and the (undesired) result or error message.

Comment: I have tried normal barchart or plot, but I don't know how to subdivide in interval the data

Comment: In anycase i will post in the main post

Comment: Have you searched for how to create a histogram?

Comment: I updated with the code, thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you for posting your code and some data! So, we are not starting from zero. What is the second column? Do you want to sum up these values in your bins? With your current code your are summing up only `1.0` per line, not the value in column 2.

Comment: The second columns is how many time the number of column 1 appears, because in the guide that i was following he was doing in this way. But the the important is the part is column 1, that i need to plot

Comment: And i think I need the second col to calculate the line of the mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script takes your data and sums up the second column within the defined bins.
If you have values of equal 100 in the first column, those values would be in the bin `100-<110`.

With `Bin(x) = floor(x/BinWidth)*BinWidth + BinWidth*0.5`, the bins are shifted by half a binwidth to let the boxes on the x-axis range from the beginning of the bin to the end of the bin (and not centered at the beginning of the respective bin).

If you explicitely want to have xtics labels like in the example graph you've shown, i.e. `10-<20`, `20-<30` etc. you would have to fiddle around with the xtic labels.

**Edit:** Forgot the mean value. There is no need for calling awk. Gnuplot can do this for you as well, check `help stats`.

**Code:**

```
### create histogram
reset session

$Data <<EOD
33.18 5
43.296 1
33.19 1
27.168 5
71.429 11
30.698 9
47.934 1
43.299 3
30.699 3
37.092 2
24.492 2
24.493 2
24.494 7
47.938 1
24.497 1
37.097 8
37.099 2
33.824 7
51.111 15
59.025 2
62.553 2
62.554 2
57.867 2
33.826 2
62.555 1
33.827 5
62.556 2
33.828 1
59.028 1
46.429 11
51.117 1
75.158 2
27.621 1
27.623 1
27.624 2
37.5 113
37.6 2
32.313 8
27.626 3
37.7 3
32.314 1
67.797 3
27.628 2
32.316 2
37.9 1
61.044 1
43.81 5
32.317 8
32.318 2
43.82 4
32.319 2
43.83 2
37.551 3
61.048 1
48.993 6
29.43 2
EOD

# Histogram
BinWidth = 10
Bin(x)   = floor(x/BinWidth)*BinWidth + BinWidth*0.5

# Mean
stats $Data u ($1*$2):2 nooutput
mean = STATS_sum_x/STATS_sum_y
set arrow 1 from mean, graph 0 to mean, graph 1 nohead lw 2 lc rgb "red" front
set label 1 sprintf("Mean: %.1f", mean) at mean, graph 1 offset 1,-0.7

set xlabel "Identity / %"
set xrange [0:100]
set xtics 10 out
set ylabel "The number of blast hits"
set style fill solid 0.3
set boxwidth BinWidth
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y

plot $Data using (Bin($1)):2 smooth freq with boxes lc "blue"
### end of code
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: thank you !! it is exactly what I was looking for and now I have understood how to do it